# Overlapping titles in the reviewer queue

Tags: bug, design

I noticed that in the "Review Suggested Edits" queue, a title that is too long overlaps with the edited version in the `side-by-side` view.

*Is this a design issue or a bug?*

Even after reloading the page, the problem persists. But this seems to be the case only if the word written together, in this case `Fastapi : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`, is too long for subdivision/correct formatting as other `Suggested Edits` do not have this problem.

**Here is the problem in a screenshot:**

[image: Overlapping titles]

*I have chosen once the tag `design` and `bug` here. Feel free to remove the irrelevant one.*